# Can't use python base environment in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, miniconda

[image: env list]
[image: vs code env list]

The base environment isn't shown in my vs code, and in vs code, it has an environment named "Miniconda3". When I try to run .ipynb files in vs code, I get this error:

> Error: Activating Python 3.7.3 64-bit ('Miniconda3': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: Command failed: d:/Miniconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate Miniconda3 && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:/Users/****/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
>   Could not find conda environment: Miniconda3
>   You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

How can I solve this without creating new environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an environment with a Python version specified so conda installs a Python interpreter, e.g. `conda create -n <yourenvname> python=3.8`.

The details of where the extension looks for environments can be found in the [environments docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments).

Comment: Thanks. Followed your suggestion and it's working now. Looks like it can only be fixed by creating new environment.